# Control parent page from child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have successfully added some controls that were on the parent page to a child page(popup) and made them control the parent page. These were javascript functions.

I now want to add this line from the parent page onto the child page:

```
   <li><a class="button icon-play play" href="#" onclick="return false;"></a></li>
```

The javascript that goes with this is :

```
// Listen for Play Button Click
    $('.button.play').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('icon-play'))
        {
            start_teleprompter();
        }
        else
        {
            stop_teleprompter();
        }
    });
```

The problem im having is that the javascript is in a file called script.js and if I can see no way of it making the script run if the link is on the child page.

Previously what I have done is added parent_window.document. to the javascript functions.

So one of the fucntions that works :(this js is in the child page)

```
function changeBGC(color)
    {
    if (parent_window && !parent_window.closed) {
    parent_window.document.getElementById("teleprompter").style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
    }
```

and the button for it is :

```
<div class="swatch turquoise" onClick="javascript:changeBGC('#1abc9c')"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this script to the child page to call functions of its parent window:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.button.play').click(function(){
            if (parent_window && !parent_window.closed) {
                if($(this).hasClass('icon-play')) {
                    parent_window.start_teleprompter();
                } else {
                    parent_window.stop_teleprompter();
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do I just change the script in script.js or add this to the child?

Comment: Add this script to your child page.

Comment: Do i do anything the the actual link?

Comment: May be refresh your page. I wrote `<script … </script>`

Comment: Oh , in that case , i have that in the child page and it is not working

Comment: But the child HTML contains `<li><a class="button icon-play play" href="#" onclick="return false;"></a></li>` ?

Comment: yes the link is the same as it is on the parent page

Comment: Could it have something to do with the script.js . If so I can post that (or a link to it). The play button works on the parent page

Comment: I havn't reproductive case (and no time to make one).

Comment: You can try, if it's a live sample.

Comment: heres a link, just run the index page and launch the popup (needs to run in internet explorer cause of security) - https://www.mediafire.com/?9y2d52e096j71wb

Comment: I run you sample. You popup-window.html doesn't contain the code I propose. I added it and it's working now.

Comment: i dont understand , i added it and it didnt work . could you send me back the app folder?

Comment: OK , so I got it working , but the button dosent work properly . It plays , but then dosent change to the pause button